# Props are not rendering inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a simple setup: I have a parent component that passes data using props to a child component. However, when I pass the props to the child component, the data is not filled in. All the tutorials and guides I've followed use the same syntax as I'm using, so I must be missing something. I just can't seem to figure out what.

```js
// LoginPage.vue
<script>
import Card from '../generic/Card.vue';
import Input from '../generic/Input.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Card,
    Input,
  }
}
</script>

<template>
    <Card>
        <template v-slot:title>Sign in</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <Input :type="text" :placeholder="Email"></Input>
        </template>
    </Card>
</template>
```

```js
// generic/Card.vue
<template>
    <div class="card rounded-md p-8 border-2 border-sgray hover:border-sgreen text-center">
        <div class="text-xl font-medium text-black">
            <slot name="title"></slot>
        </div>

        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
// generic/Input.vue

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        value: String,
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <input type="{{ type }}" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" value="{{ value }}"/>
</template>
```

When I take a look at the code in the browser, I get this:

```html
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
   <div class="flex h-screen">
      <div class="m-auto">
         <div class="card rounded-md p-8 border-2 border-sgray hover:border-sgreen text-center">
            <div class="text-xl font-medium text-black">Sign in</div>
            <input type="{{ type }}" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This line is the problem:

```html
<input type="{{ type }}" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}">
```

The data does not get filled in where I want them to, but it just returns `{{ type }}` or `{{ placeholder }}`, without actually filling in the passed props.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache `{{  }}` is actually used for display purposes.
If we want to bind any variable inside an HTML attribute, we should use the v-bind directive.

```
<input v-bind:type="type" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder">
// OR
<input :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder">
```

**A small tip-**

1. We should avoid using the [reserved keywords](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) as variable names like type, define, and many more. It can create confusion.
2. What you did is also fine but it's better to use the props like this-

```
props: {
  type: {
    type: String,
    // add any other validation
  },
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    // add any other validation
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. However, I'm still confused as when to use `{{ }}` and when to use the `bind(:)` syntax. Do you have any pointers for me? For example, in this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-props-in-vuejs/ - they are using the `{{ }}` notation and not the `bind(:)`.

Comment: When we want to use the values which can be work like attributes, use the bind(:) operator, like- `<div :id="id"></div>`

Comment: And when we want to display the values inside any element, then use {{}} operator, like

`<div>{{ type }}</div>`

Comment: Ah, I see. That clears it up. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. I also edited the answer to mention the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind props in component:

```
<input :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder" :value="value"/>
```